# ayuda con el paso de parámetros por referencia en c

Tags: c, punteros

Se como se opera un puntero en otra funcion pero desearia aprender a como operar el valor de ese mismo puntero en otra funcion sin salir de la primera, es decir, salgo de main con una variable **valor** con un valor de 45 y en la primera funcion con con puntero le sumo 15 y en esa misma funcionn me dirigo a otra en donde le pienso sumar a mi variable **valor** otros 15, pero falla.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void asig2(int valor);
void asig1(int *valor);`

int main(){

  int valor;
  valor = 45;
  printf("%d\n",valor); // 45

  asig1(&valor); //primera funcion

  printf("Por lo tanto valor final es: ");
  printf("%d\n",valor); // 75
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

void asig1(int *valor){

  *valor += 15;

  printf("%d\n",*valor); // 60

  asig2(*valor); //segunda funcion
}

void asig2(int valor){

  valor += 15;

  printf("%d\n",valor); // 75

}
```

y al ejecutar el codigo me imprime lo siguiente:

`45
  60
  75
  Por lo tanto valor final es:
  60`

Comment: En `asig2` también debes recibir ese valor por referencia: `void asig2(int *valor)`. Actualmente lo recibes por referencia en `asig1`, pero luego lo recibes por valor en `asig2`, por eso es que el valor _no regresa_, pues se modifica la _copia_ que se hace en el stack.

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque en tu segunda función el argumento se pasa por valor.
Ahora tienes dos opciones:

1) Hacer *asig2* reciba el argumento por referencia

```
void asig2(int *valor){
  *valor += 15;
  printf("%d\n",*valor); // 75
}
```

2) Hacer que asig2 devuelva el entero modificado y que asig1 asigne este nuevo valor

*asig2*

```
int asig2(int valor){
  valor += 15;
  printf("%d\n",valor); // 75
  return valor;
}
```

*asig1*

```
void asig1(int *valor){
  *valor += 15;
  printf("%d\n",*valor); // 60
  *valor = asig2(*valor); //segunda funcion
}
```

Yo optaría por 1). Aunque ambas soluciones son semánticamente iguales